# Mysql fetch rows only contain a row with certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Lets say, my tables has the following rows:

```
  id | prop1 | prop2 
______________________
  1    foo      a
  2    bar      a
  3    foo      b
  4    bar      b
  5    foo      c
```

Now in this case, i want to get rows grouped by `prop1` but ignore the groups that don't contain a row with `prop2=c`

So the intended result is:

```
1 foo a
3 foo b
5 foo c
```

Note, now there is only one group in the example but i want to be able to get all of them. How can i achieve this approach?

Comment: Please clarify your answer. Grouping by `prop1` can have different `prop2`'s, which one you want to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exists clause to remove all the rows if it does not have prop2 = c using below query.

```
select * 
from your_table t1
where 
exists (select 1 from your_table t2 where t1.prop1 = t2.prop1
        and t2.prop2 = 'c')
```

Explaination: Exists caluse will return true if it finds c for that group else false.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected result is not grouped by `prop1`. If it was grouped by `prop1` then you would get only one record in the result.

To achieve the above, we can write a simple `SELECT` with sub-query, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE prop1 IN (
 SELECT prop1 FROM table WHERE prop2 = 'c'
);
```

Comment: i don't mean `group by`, the rows are listed according to `prop1`

Comment: @eyurdakul in which case, the above query should work fine

Comment: yeah, it works fine but in my case, i execute this query on production and it is a huge table (and there are more conditions than just prop1 and prop2). I will give this an upvote but this is not the one that solved my problem.

Comment: @eyurdakul I have removed `distinct` so it should be better now. Also, having an index on `prop2` will speed it up..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE prop2 != "c" GROUP BY prop1
```

This line is gonna delete att rows with C and the group everything else on prop1

Answer (score 0):

The following query fetches all record with prop2 = 'c' (T1)
and joins them on all records (T2)  that have an equal prop1:

```
select T2.*
from    TABLE T1
join TABLE T2 ON T1.prop1=T2.prop1
WHERE T1.prop2 = 'c'
GROUP BY id
```